# An ordinary generating function for the Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics

I'm currently struggling with ordinary generating functions(OGF) and was hoping somebody could point me in the direction of determining the OGF for the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $\sum_{n=k}^\infty S(n,k) x^n$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Generating_function

Comment: That's a perfect link for the OGF but I'm having problems with proving that it's the OGf not just what the OGF is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). There you'll learn much of what there is about generating functions. A next step could be Flajolet and Sedgewick's ["Analytic combinatorics"](http://ac.cs.princeton.edu/) (careful, that one is quite a bit heavier going).

Comment: You can also read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2308567/stirling-numbers-of-the-second-kind-how-to-obtain-a-recurrence-relation-from-a/2785732#2785732) on how to apply a Norlund-Rice (contour) integral to a known identity for the Stirling numbers of the second kind to arrive at the same OGF.